# MinGW in Code::Blocks not linking static OpenSSL Library

Tags: c++, openssl, codeblocks

I'm trying to take advantage of some of OpenSSL's EC cryptography and ECDSA functionality to make a rudimentary blockchain simulation, but I've run into a major roadblock. I'm using the Code::Blocks IDE, and I've installed OpenSSL using the 64-bit binary found here: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html.

In Linker Settings, I added OpenSSL-Win64\lib\openssl.lib

In Search Directories > Compiler, I added OpenSSL-Win64\include

In Search Directories > Linker, I added OpenSSL-Win64\lib

However, when I compile, I get the "undefined reference to (function name)" error for every OpenSSL function I try to use. However, the compiler seems to be successfully including the header files, since it recognizes the new data types like EC_KEY. I suspect a linking error, but I'm not sure what could be wrong, since I have the link paths and static library linked as above.

Here is my build log:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -LD:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib -LD:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -LD:\OpenSSL-Win64 -o bin\Debug\BlockchainSim.exe obj\Debug\main.o     obj\Debug\src\Block.o obj\Debug\src\BlockchainNode.o obj\Debug\src\Transaction.o     obj\Debug\src\Valuable.o   D:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\openssl.lib
obj\Debug\src\BlockchainNode.o: In function `ZN14BlockchainNodeC2Ei':
F:/School/Barrett/BlockchainSim/src/BlockchainNode.cpp:18: undefined reference to `EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name'
F:/School/Barrett/BlockchainSim/src/BlockchainNode.cpp:21: undefined reference to `BN_new'
F:/School/Barrett/BlockchainSim/src/BlockchainNode.cpp:22: undefined reference to `EC_KEY_set_private_key'
F:/School/Barrett/BlockchainSim/src/BlockchainNode.cpp:25: undefined reference to `BN_CTX_new'
F:/School/Barrett/BlockchainSim/src/BlockchainNode.cpp:26: undefined reference to `BN_CTX_start'
F:/School/Barrett/BlockchainSim/src/BlockchainNode.cpp:28: undefined reference to `EC_KEY_get0_group'
F:/School/Barrett/BlockchainSim/src/BlockchainNode.cpp:29: undefined reference to `EC_POINT_new'
F:/School/Barrett/BlockchainSim/src/BlockchainNode.cpp:30: undefined reference to `EC_POINT_mul'
F:/School/Barrett/BlockchainSim/src/BlockchainNode.cpp:31: undefined reference to `EC_KEY_set_public_key'
F:/School/Barrett/BlockchainSim/src/BlockchainNode.cpp:34: undefined reference to `EC_POINT_free'
F:/School/Barrett/BlockchainSim/src/BlockchainNode.cpp:35: undefined reference to `BN_CTX_end'
F:/School/Barrett/BlockchainSim/src/BlockchainNode.cpp:36: undefined reference to `BN_CTX_free'
F:/School/Barrett/BlockchainSim/src/BlockchainNode.cpp:37: undefined reference to `BN_clear_free'
obj\Debug\src\BlockchainNode.o: In function `ZN14BlockchainNodeD2Ev':
F:/School/Barrett/BlockchainSim/src/BlockchainNode.cpp:42: undefined reference to `EC_KEY_free'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
15 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

I'm hoping I'm just missing something simple here since I'm new to linking static libraries. A lot of similar issues seem to be solved by adding options to compile commands, but since I'm using Code::Blocks and linking OpenSSL as a static library, I'm not sure if those apply here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you also compile openssl.lib etc. with the same compiler and flags?

Comment: No, but that wasn't necessary due to the nature of the binary I used. It basically installs and compiles OpenSSL for you.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The issue was that I had no C:/MinGW folder (as Code::Blocks installed MinGW within its own directory). I'm guessing the binary I used tries to detect existing compilers and compiles the library differently depending on what it finds.

I fixed it by installing default MinGW (with MSYS, in case that matters) with the default path (C:/MinGW) and then reinstalling the 32-bit binary OpenSSL linked in the original question, also in the default path (C:/OpenSSL-Win32). This made it so that within the C:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib folder, there was a new MinGW folder which I then included in the linker search directories.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, can you add the full command that worked?